# Issues when importing a Symfony project from Github to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, symfony, github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I import a Symfony project from GitHub to IntelliJ IDEA following the  [official method of JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html), I get some weird errors :

- The Project Navigator Layout becomes horizontal instead of vertical
- Even when I install all the dependencies through composer (without errors), install Symfony plugin and running my project very well, I get many symfony components red. I don't really know why !

Here is a screenshot of that project :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Close Intellij Idea
- Go to your project directory using terminal `cd <project/ditectory>`
- Delete `.idea` folder `rm -rf .idea`
- Open your project again in intellij.